# Kohana ORM serialize columns, JSON and stdClass

Tags: json, serialization, orm, kohana

I'm wondering how people are dealing with the stdClass that results from json_decode run on the columns in `_serialize_columns` in Kohana's ORM.

The problem I'm having is that I set the column as an array, which is serialized and is all good. Later, when I retrieve it, it comes back as a stdClass. This is all good for most things, but if I attempt use something like `Arr::path()` on that value, it of course can't deal with (a problem with `array_shift` I think).

One option I tried was casting the resulting value to an array, but this only works for the first level of the array. So, I then looped through the array casting everything to an array. This worked, but seems like a considerable hack.

What is everyone else doing to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

As a recommendation from @zeelot, I filed a ticket in Kohana's ticketing system: http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/4188

I also overrode the Kohana_ORM method `_unserialize_value()` as follows:

```
protected function _unserialize_value($value) {
    return json_decode($value, TRUE);
}
```

Related discussion here: http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/9465/orm-serialize-columns-json-and-stdclass